# Convert LaTeX dollar sign to \( \)

Tags: regex, latex

I need to convert plain text files containing math with the dollar sign notation `$myformula$` to the `\(myformula\)` notation. However I want the double dollar notation `$$myformula$$` to *not* be replaced.

Up until now I was doing this by hand by finding an replacing all dollar signs with a space before them by the opening syntax `\(` and all other dollar signs by the close syntax `\)` and correcting the remaining mistakes by hand (like beginning of line, double dollar sings). I think a regex command I could use to convert multiple files via the Terminal would accellerate this a lot.

Here is an example how it looks and should look like:

Before:

> This is $a+b_{k}+c$ sentence.
>
> Another test $s_\text{hi}+3$.
>
> $x=y$ there.
>
> $$y=z$$ why?
>
> $$z=z$$
>
> This could be ($3^2$, $x_1$).

After:

> `This is \(a+b_{k}+c\) sentence.
>   Another test \(s_\text{hi}+3\).
>   \(x=y\) there.
>   $$y=z$$ why?
>   $$z=z$$
>   This could be (\(3^2\), \(x_1\)).`

Thanks!

Comment: You should also change `$$`...`$$` to `\[`...`\]`. See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>**Regex**: `([^\$])\$([^\$]+)\$([^\$])`</strike>
**Regex**: `(^|[^\$])\$([^\$]+)\$([^\$]|$)`
**Substitution**: `$1\\($2\\)$3`

Pretty messy with 3 capture groups, but it seems to do exactly what is needed.

First capture anything that isn't `$`, followed by anything wrapped by `$`, followed by another character that isn't `$`, and replace it all with the second group wrapped in parenthesis, wrapped by the first and third group.

Edit: The first capture group should also check for `^`, the beginning of the file, and the third group should check for `$`, the end of the file. The new Demo has examples that would break under my first statement.

<strike>[**Bad Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2BjsAb/1)</strike>
[**Good Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2BjsAb/2)

Comment: No problem, regex can be confusing but very powerful once you can wrap your head around it. Make sure you see my edit so you don't run into a problem I noticed.

Comment: This was very useful for me. One caveat is that it won't work automatically if strings of math mode stretch across lines. For that, one might need an `m` modifier

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: `\$([^\$]+)\$` **Substitution**: `\\($1\\)`

**Details**:

- `()` Capturing Group
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Input**:

```
$myformula$
```

**Output**:

```
Full match  0-11    `$myformula$`
Group 1.    1-10    `myformula`
```

**Result**:

```
\(myformula\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTDS0F/3)

Comment: Thanks! This is almost working except that the double dollars get changed which they shouldn't.